# How to "invalidate" MFMessageComposeViewController (Obj-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an `IBAction` which opens up a text message dialog when pressed, using a `MFMessageComposeViewController`. But I have an `if` statement containing some statements and I want to make the `MFMessageComposeViewController` "invalidated" if one of the if statements is true when pressed on the same `IBAction`.

So my question is simple, how do I "invalidate" a `MFMessageComposeViewController`? Or at least make the dialog not appear?

EDIT (code):

```
if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])

{

    NSMutableArray *recipients = [NSMutableArray array];

    if (loadString.length > 0) {
        [recipients addObject:loadString];
    }

    if (loadString2.length > 0) {
        [recipients addObject:loadString2];

    }

    if (loadString3.length > 0) {
        [recipients addObject:loadString3];

    }

    [controller setRecipients:recipients];
    [controller setBody:theLocation];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];

} else {

    NSLog(@"Can't open text.");

}

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by invalidate? And update your question with some relevant code.

Comment: Like, making the text message view not appear. I don't know how to put it. Make the MFMessageComposeViewController cancel, and not open? If that make any sense :/

Comment: If you don't want to show it, don't show it. Only show it if some appropriate condition is true.

Comment: But the code for showing it is in the same IBAction, which makes it pop up anyway...

Comment: You need to post the right code. Post the code for your action where you present the message controller.

Comment: You took out the code with the `if` statement. Anyway, don't call presentViewController unless your `if` statement passes.

Answer (score 1):

Because `MFMessageComposeViewController` is also an instance of `UIViewController`. You can just dismiss it using `dismissViewControllerAnimated` if you don't want it anymore.

And you better to handle `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` and here is a sample code for it:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
    switch (result) {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled: {
            [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(){
                [SVProgressHUD showInfoWithStatus:@"The email is cancelled"];
            }];
            break;
        }

        case MFMailComposeResultFailed: {

            [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Failed to send"];

            break;
        }

        case MFMailComposeResultSaved: {
            [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(){
                [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"The draft is saved"];
            }];
            break;
        }

        case MFMailComposeResultSent: {
            [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(){
                [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Sent successfully"];
            }];
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question seems to be about how not to show it in the first place. Not how to dismiss it once it is shown.

Comment: Hmmmm, true though. But the requirement is not as clear. I think he's asking about the popping dialog than the `MFMessageComposeViewController `. Anyway, you are more than welcomed to edit my answer. @rmaddy

Comment: Then, I have to ask what do you mean by *invalidate*. And where do you call it? Do you mean to deallocate?

Comment: I meant to cancel it, I didn't know the term :/

Comment: What do you want to cancel. I don't really get it. The `controller ` in your code? Then, just dismiss it. Do you have other concerns?